# xquery: select ancestor several levels up from parent

Tags: xquery, ancestor

I am trying to select the value of the <li> ancestor node just previous to the parent node. Here is a sample of the document, im-trg.xml:

```
<trg>
<category>
    <h2>Accounting and Auditing</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>Laws and Regulations
        <ul>
            <li><a href="url1">Regulation S-X</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Staff Guidance
        <ul>
            <li>No Action Letters
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="url2">Robert Van Grover, Esq., Seward and Kissel LLP</a> (November 5, 2013)</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</category>
</trg>
```

Here is my query:

```
for $x in doc("C:\im-trg.xml")//li/a
return 
<item>
<title>{data($x)}</title>
<documentType>{data($x/ancestor::li[2])}</documentType>
<category>{data($x/ancestor::category/h2)}</category>
</item>
```

I am getting:

```
<item>
  <title>Regulation S-X</title>
  <documentType>Laws and RegulationsRegulation S-X</documentType>
  <category>Accounting and Auditing</category>
</item>
```

For <documentType>, I want to select only the ancestor <li> immediately previous to the <li> parent of the <a>, which indicates the type of document, so I want:

```
<item>
  <title>Regulation S-X</title>
  <documentType>Laws and Regulations</documentType>
  <category>Accounting and Auditing</category>
</item>
```

and

```
<item>
  <title>Robert Van Grover, Esq., Seward and Kissel LLP</title>
  <documentType>No Action Letters</documentType>
  <category>Accounting and Auditing</category>
</item>
```

I don't think I can come down from the root because the parent <li> is sometimes double nested and sometimes triple nested.

Comment: `ancestor::li[2]` is selecting the second `<li>` ancestor, looking upward from the starting node since `ancestor::` is a reverse axis. If you want the closest one, change that to `ancestor::li[1]`

Comment: right, li[1] is the same as the parent, li[2] is the next li toward the root. The li[2] text is I want to capture to populate an xml element (the documentType value), but without any text from the child ul/lis. I can't figure out why I am getting li[2] + li[1]. Maybe the return is correct, in this case li[1] is a descendant of li[2] so both are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text value of an element is the concatenation of *all* its text-node descendants. If you only want the text immediately contained by the element, you should explicitly select its text children, eg

```
data($x/ancestor::li[2]/text())
```

Comment: For completeness, it should be noted that SQL Server's implementation of XQuery does not support the `ancestor::` axis step. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/path-expressions-specifying-axis